# How to get server error message in client side Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, titanium-mobile

My server checks before saving data in the database. Then if server cannot save data into database, it sends an error message.

In my client side app, how can I get this error and display it?

This is my client side http request-

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            var service_ = service.value;


            if (start_pick < end_pick) {
                var jsondata = [{
                    start_time : new Date(start_pick),
                    end_time : new Date(end_pick),
                    service : service_,

                }];

                var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
                xhr.setTimeout(10000);

                xhr.open("POST", "url");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
                xhr.onerror = function(e) {
                     //Ti.API.debug(e.error);
                    // console.log(e.error)
                    Titanium.API.info("Error in connecting to server !!");
                    alert("Error in connecting to server !!");
                };

                xhr.onload = function(e) {
                    //alert(e)
                    if (e.error) {
                        alert(this.responseText);
                    } else  {
                        windowAddDataInvoce.close();
                }


                };
```

this is my server side "POST" code

```
app.post('/collections/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body[0])
  req.collection.findOne({"service":req.body[0].service}, function(e, result){
      if(result){
        console.log(result); console.log(e)
        res.send({error:"Task already exits"})
      }
      else{
        req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
        if (e) return next(e)
        res.send(results)

         })
      }
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a correct HTTP-Status.
In Express, you do this as a first argument to send, so:

`res.send(500, errorMessage)` or in newer Version `res.status(500).body(errorMessage)`.

With every other status than 200, it should trigger your error-callback in the XHR-Request.

Comment: The error message is within the body of the response. I dont know where your Titanium API puts this information - should be in the docs somewhere. Maybe as a second parameter to the error callback?

But let me tell you that it is a bad pattern to send actual error messages from the server to the client - especially no stack traces or anything like that as it could reveal your servers architecture and thus make it a security threat. Define Error Messages on your client dependin the HTTP Status of the server.